# ArrayList<class> swap method

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, compare, swap

```
  public void sortDatabase(){
        for(int j=0;j<productDatabase.size()-1;j++){
        for(int i =0;i<productDatabase.size()-j-1;i++){
    if(compareTo(i)){
        Collections.swap(productDatabase,i,i++ );  //Με την Χρήση της Collections βιβλιοθήκης κάνω SWAP! Πρέπει να βάλω την βιβλιοθήκη όμως!

    }


    }
    }
}

public boolean compareTo(int index){

    if(productDatabase.get(index).getPrice() > productDatabase.get(index++).getPrice()){
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;



}
```

Last time i posted my answer in a very bad way. Sorry for my english that really suck , but here is my problem. I 've declared an ArrayList < class of Product > productDatabase  .  Product class has some fields in it. The main problem is that i cannot sort my productDatabase elements .

I use Collections.swap()  but can i use that method even if my ArrayList consists of elements that are another object ?

Also i want you to take a look at my compareTo method that i wrote which is boolean and returns me a value to know if swap of elements is needed.

Thanks in advance ... and feeling sorry for my latest first bad post.

Comment: If you just want to sort it,implement Comparable in the class of the productDatabase object and then use Collections.sort

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to reinvent the wheel by implementing sorting algorithms using `swap()`.  `Collections` already provides a `sort()` method using a nice implementation of mergesort.

Implement a [`Comparator<Product>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and use [`Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<T>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort the `List` according to a custom comparison criteria.

```
Comparator<Product> PRICE_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Product>() { 
    @Override
    public int compare(Product o1, Product o2) {
        // Check for nulls if necessary
        return o1.getPrice().compareTo(o2.getPrice());
    }
}

List<Product> sortedList = Collections.sort(unsortedList, PRICE_COMPARATOR);
```

If your `List` is not a `List<Product>`, but a `List<Object>` instead (it might contain items that are not `Product`s), you could implement a `Comparator<Object>` and use `instanceof` inside it to leave non `Product` items at the end of the `List`.

Or iterate to filter it while adding only `Products` to an ordered data structure such as a `TreeSet<Product>`, providing your own `Comparator<Product>`.