# ArrayList<class> collection.swap method

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, swap

I have search many many sites but the only thing which I found was [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765243/arraylistclass-swap-method)

I have a BSNode class. I have make an `ArrayList<BSNode> data` and now I want to swap two variables but i face this error :

```
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<BSNode>
```

is there any way I can swap this two? when I want to just compare two variables, I just implement comparable in BSNode class and I override one method. but what should I do to SWAP them in array list?

i have this method :

```
public static void permutation (ArrayList<BSNode> data, int k, int n)
```

and I want to do this:

```
 for (int i = k; i < n; i++) { 
     Collections.swap(data, data[k], data[i]); 
 }
```

Comment: Share your code, please.

Comment: Can you able to post your code

Comment: @kocko there is nothing more to share :D there is just a class named BSNode which has a constructor and getter and setter for : private double prob;
private int key;
private int level;
private BSNode parent;
private BSNode left;
private BSNode right;

and another class for some algorithm which I need to use collection.swap for an ArrayList<BSNode> data.

Comment: And what do you want to swap then ? It's not clear from your question...

Comment: @kocko i have this method : 
public static void permutation (ArrayList<BSNode> data, int k, int n)
and I want to do this:
for (int i = k; i < n; i++) 
{
 Collections.swap(data, data[k], data[i]);
}

Comment: And why don’t you use `Collections.swap(data, k, i);`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use  `Collections.swap(data, k,i);`  instead of `Collections.swap(data, data[k], data[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Collections.swap(List<?> list, int i, int j);
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the javadoc [`Collections.swap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap%28java.util.List,%20int,%20int%29) takes a List argument, and 2 ints, representing the elements you want swapped. So The solution you are looking for would be something like this

```
Collections.swap(data, k,i);
```

Collections.swap

```
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j)

    list - The list in which to swap elements.
    i - the index of one element to be swapped.
    j - the index of the other element to be swapped.
```